# mysql multiple ORDER BY trouble self joining from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, self-join

I'm going to phrase this in sentence form first and then in data form.

What I want to do in sentence from:
"Show me three car manufacturers sorted by the the most recent to release a new car,
along with all of the cars those manufacturers have made."

SO I want the data to come out something like this:

```
Ford, ModelA, 2012
Ford, ModelG, 2008
Toyota, ModelH, 2011
Toyota, ModelJ, 2009
Honda, ModelN, 2010
Hondda, ModelK, 2007
```

My problem is that when I try to order them together by manufacturer, it UNDOES the ordering by release date.

```
Ford, ModelA, 2012
Ford, ModelG, 2008
Honda, ModelN, 2010 <--wrong, Toyota should go here
Hondda, ModelK, 2007
Toyota, ModelH, 2011
Toyota, ModelJ, 2009
```

And if I don't try to order them together by manufacturer after getting release date,
I get lines joined out of order depending on how they are ordered in the database.

```
Ford, ModelA, 2012
Honda, ModelN, 2010<--wrong, want to finish Fords before moving to next latest release
Ford, ModelG, 2008
Hondda, ModelK, 2007
Toyota, ModelH, 2011
Toyota, ModelJ, 2009
```

I've tried various attempts at INNER JOIN on a subquery like,

```
SELECT * FROM cars 
INNER JOIN (SELECT m.manufactuer 
            FROM cars AS m 
            ORDER BY m.year DESC LIMIT 3) subq 
ON cars.manufacturer=subq.object 
ORDER BY cars.manufacturer
```

(Some other attemts where insufficient because the LIMIT can't be used on all types of subquerys).

I'm open to splitting it up into mutiple querys.

```
+---------------+---------+--------+
|manufacturer   | model   | year   |
|---------------|---------|--------|
|ford           |modelA   |2008    |
|toyota         | modelS  |2010    |
```

**EDIT:**

kordirko's answer and some of my variations of it, return the manufactures in the correct order but the year is overridden by the subquery match. So it produces something like

```
Ford, ModelA, 2012
Ford, ModelG, 2012<--
Honda, ModelN, 2010
Hondda, ModelK, 2010<--
Toyota, ModelH, 2011
Toyota, ModelJ, 2011<-- wrong, need it to show actual year of model, not year from match of the most recent
```

**SOLUTION**

RIGHT JOIN seems to give a useable solution:

```
SELECT cars.manufacturer, cars.year FROM cars 
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT m.manufacturer FROM cars AS m ORDER BY m.year DESC LIMIT 3) subq 
ON cars.manufacturer=subq.manufacturer
```

Haven't put it through the full rigors, but seems to work in cursory test.

Comment: try `ORDER BY subq.year DESC, cars.year DESC`

Comment: @kordiko- Close. It orders correctly by release date, and groups them correctly by manufacturer, but the inner join replaces all the year values with the year value matched in the sub-query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT c.manufactuer,
       c.model,
       c.year,
       s.year As most_recent_year
FROM cars c
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT m.manufactuer, max(m.year) year
  FROM cars AS m 
  GROUP BY m.manufactuer
  ORDER BY year DESC LIMIT 3
) s
ON c.manufactuer=s.manufactuer 
ORDER BY s.year DESC, c.year DESC
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fac25/2

Comment: This is really close. It orders correctly by release date, and groups them correctly by manufacturer, but the inner join replaces all the year values with the year value matched in the sub-query.

Comment: The query is using `SELECT *` instead of explicitely list required column names, and this is a reson why a year column is being replaced by another column with the same name. Generally using of `SELECT *` in queries is not recommended. I've corrected the query in my answer and appended a link to simple demo.